# Refreshing a token best practice

Tags: security, session

I have been asked to implement refreshing a token. A token ID is the same as a session ID. I have considered resetting the session's idle time to 0 and continue using the same session ID for the session.

Does this violate security best practice? Is it security best practice to return a new token ID in this case to prevent session fixation attacks?

Answer (score 1):

Usually tokens have:

- An Idle Timeout
- A Life Span

Both of these help prevent the "forever" token.

For example the idle timeout may be 5 minutes and the life span may be 2 hours.  If the token is idle for 5 minutes it gets invalidated or if it been in use for over 2 hours it gets invalidated.  Both of these limit the usefulness of a token and if these conditions are met, the user is forced to authenticate again.

Your timing settings may vary based on the type of application that is being developed.  So use whatever value makes sense in your scenario.

Also, I would never refresh a token, I would always give out a new one an invalidate the old one.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, then **refresh token can be implemented along with access token as the idea of refresh token is that if an access token is compromised, because it is short-lived, the attacker has a limited window in which to abuse it**.

Refresh tokens, if compromised, are useless because the attacker requires the client id and secret in addition to the refresh token in order to gain an access token.

Here is similar thread : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487991/why-does-oauth-v2-have-both-access-and-refresh-tokens)

Reference help : [reference](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg06687.html)